# Search view widget and Icon not showing up in the action bar

Tags: android

I am a beginner to Android. Trying to add a search a widget in the action bar. 
Here is my menu file code ("main_acitivity.xml"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

My MainActivity class code is:

```
package com.example.fragment;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.fragment.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent= new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I have tried "android.widget.SearchView" as well but it is not even showing the icon. Could you please advise what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you missed these:

```
 xmlns:yourappname="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and

```
yourappname:showAsAction="always"
yourappname:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Comment: Is this necessary cause I am using API min SDK version 18 ?

Comment: if you are using API 18 you should not use SearchView from support library, in API 11 and above it is provided, so if you are using support version those lines are necessary else do not use support version(android.support.v7.widget)